# Edit form for django comments

Tags: django, django-comments

I am using django comments apps to allow user to submit comments, but there is not any edit form for the comment. Does the comment app support an edit form or do I have to make one of my own.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and have written a small portable app which aims to add edit functionality to the comments framework. Please note that it has not been tested, and it may be security issues with it. But you can check it out at [github](https://github.com/rhblind/django-comments-extension).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't built in to the comment app so it's something you'll have to write yourself. You will need to consider how to confirm that the person requesting to edit a comment actually wrote the comment. This is ok if you are dealing with logged in users but will be difficult for anonymous comments.

Comment: I understand the identity of the person is an issue, that's why I will give the editing option only to logged in user